# ensure uniqueness (distinct record) with JPQL or SQL?  Or both?

Tags: mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, persistence, jpql

How can I prevent TopLink from duplicating existing data?  Is it even a good idea to do that with Java code, or should that be built into the database and let inserts fail?

In this case, I want to ensure that `newsgroups.newsgroup` is unique and that `articles.header_id_string` is also unique.

Probably the best approach would be to simply run a query for uniqueness in Java JPQL?

Schema:

```
mysql> 
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_nntp      |
+---------------------+
| articles            |
| newsgroups          |
| newsgroups_articles |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe newsgroups;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| newsgroup | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe articles;
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject          | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content          | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| number           | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sent             | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| header_id_string | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe newsgroups_articles;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| article_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| newsgroup_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The Newsgroup entity:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "newsgroups", catalog = "nntp", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Newsgroups.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM Newsgroup n"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Newsgroups.findById", query = "SELECT n FROM Newsgroup n WHERE n.id = :id")})
public class Newsgroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "newsgroup", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String newsgroup;

    public Newsgroup() {
    }

    public Newsgroup(Folder f){
        newsgroup = f.getFullName();
    }

    public Newsgroup(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Newsgroup(Integer id, String newsgroup) {
        this.id = id;
        this.newsgroup = newsgroup;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNewsgroup() {
        return newsgroup;
    }

    public void setNewsgroup(String newsgroup) {
        this.newsgroup = newsgroup;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Newsgroup)) {
            return false;
        }
        Newsgroup other = (Newsgroup) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Newsgroups[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

And the Article entity:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.controller.MessageBean;

@Entity
@Table(name = "articles", catalog = "nntp", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Articles.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Articles.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Articles.findByNumber", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.number = :number"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Articles.findBySent", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.sent = :sent")})
public class Article implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "subject", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String subject;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String content;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private int number;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "sent", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date sent;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "header_id_string", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    private String headerIdString;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "newsgroupId")
    private Collection<NewsgroupsArticles> newsgroupsArticlesCollection;

    public Article() {
    }

    public Article(MessageBean messageBean) {
        subject = messageBean.getSubject();
        content = messageBean.getContent();
        sent = messageBean.getSent();
        number = messageBean.getNumber();
        headerIdString = "dummy";
    }

    public Article(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Article(Integer id, String subject, String content, int number, Date sent, String headerIdString) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
        this.number = number;
        this.sent = sent;
        this.headerIdString = headerIdString;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Date getSent() {
        return sent;
    }

    public void setSent(Date sent) {
        this.sent = sent;
    }

    public String getHeaderIdString() {
        return headerIdString;
    }

    public void setHeaderIdString(String headerIdString) {
        this.headerIdString = headerIdString;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<NewsgroupsArticles> getNewsgroupsArticlesCollection() {
        return newsgroupsArticlesCollection;
    }

    public void setNewsgroupsArticlesCollection(Collection<NewsgroupsArticles> newsgroupsArticlesCollection) {
        this.newsgroupsArticlesCollection = newsgroupsArticlesCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Article)) {
            return false;
        }
        Article other = (Article) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Articles[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *should that be built into the database and let inserts fail?*

Absolutely, put it into the database.

It's your "last line of defense" and there is hardly a way around it. I you only have it your Java code you are not protected against faulty SQL scripts or programming errors.

You can still check in your code though e.g. to show the user a nicer error message.

Comment: you do that by making a column distinct?

Comment: @Thufir: you do that typically by creating a primary key. But you can also create a unique index or a unique constraint.